# Azure function saving temp pdf file from inputstream is corrupted

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I have uploaded a pdf to a blob storage which when downloaded through MS Azure Explorer is absolutely fine.

I have an Azure function that get's triggered by a queue and also has an input binding to a blob which is named in the queue message.

When I write the incoming blob to disk, the size is doubled. Also the pdf is corrupt and can't be opened in a pdf-reader. When opened in notepad the characters are different from what appears in the original file. Seems like an encoding issue but we are dealing with bytes and not text, so not sure why this is happening.

Here is my code (using python 3):

```
import azure.functions as func
import tempfile
import os.path

def main(msg: func.QueueMessage, inputblob: func.InputStream, outputTable: func.Out[str]) -> None:

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
        f_name1 = os.path.join(td, "old.pdf")
        with open(f_name1, 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(inputblob.read())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this looks broken, the first few bytes are altered, maybe more (*marvin3.jpg* is the source image in blob storage).

[image: hex dump]

[image: imgcat on bad image]

As a workaround, just add this to your `function.json` blob input binding:

```
"dataType": "binary"
```

as in:

```
{
  "name": "inputBlob",
  "type": "blob",
  "dataType": "binary",
  "direction": "in",
  "path": "images/input_image.jpg",
  "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
}
```

[You shouldn't need to put that in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python) (it's only needed for the JavaScript worker) but i guess there's a bug somewhere in the SDK that prevents the right type being inferred.

Full working example:

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputBlob: func.InputStream) -> func.HttpResponse:
    blob = inputBlob.read()

    with open("out.jpg", "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(blob)

    return func.HttpResponse(
            "Done. Binary data written to out.jpg",
            status_code=200
        )
```

[image: imgcat on good image]

[This end to end test they have in the Python worker repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/blob/8fdab32c43a41875e7ccbe34ca2a1212d85f4c7b/tests/endtoend/blob_functions/get_blob_as_bytes/function.json#L13) also seems to suggest that `"dataType": "binary"` should be there when using blob input bindings (no matter the file type you should get bytes).

If you're trying to cast the input blob as `inputBlob: bytes` instead of `inputBlob: func.InputStream`, the problem becomes more apparent if you don't have `dataType` specified:

```
Exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The Python worker gives you back a string instead of bytes.

I have [opened an issue here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/51075) for the docs to be updated.

Comment: for those who use decorators in python you should specify the data_type like this
`@app.blob_input(arg_name="blob", path="", connection="", data_type="BINARY")
def trigger_function(blob: func.InputStream):`